# How does the "Google Play Games" app by Google, Inc avoid requiring permissions?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

This is really odd to me. I just downloaded the [Google Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games) app (distributed by Google, Inc.) and was shown that on my device that it required no special permissions (on device):

[image: Google Play Games' required permissions on device]

This is peculiar because using the application there are definitely quite a few things it does that should normally require permissions. Network access, accounts access, etc. Also, all other apps by Google, Inc. that I've checked still require permissions where expected...

Another oddity is that looking at the app on the Play Store via my computer it shows that it does require a permission, although it is only access to accounts and not all the other permissions one would expect:

[image: Google Play Games' required permissions on computer]

My question, is how is it possible for the application not to require the necessary permissions and how can a discrepancy between viewing the store on device and through a web browser be explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is it possible for the application not to require the necessary permissions

It may not be doing those operations itself. It may be having a third-party perform those actions for it. For example, it might use a custom `signature`-level permission to have the Play Services Framework app do those things on its behalf.

> how can a discrepancy between viewing the store on device and through a web browser be explained?

Conceivably, there could be multiple APKs, with differing permissions. At the time of the Web dialog, you have not chosen a device, and so they present the worst-case permissions. On the device, the specific APK is known, and so they present the device-specific permissions.

That's just a guess, though, and I have no idea if that's what they're doing, or even if it's possible for the Play Store's multiple-APK support to handle different APKs with different sets of permissions.

Comment: That makes adequate sense. I had assumed that the Play Store would know which device of mine required which permissions in the same fashion that it knows which devices are incompatible with a potential app... I might try installing on multiple devices to see if any show those permissions on device...

Answer (score 0):

It leverages on google play services.